# How to make facebook app with Single Sign On enabled?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am a beginner developer.I have android app which plays national anthem when pressed relevant button

I want to have facebook login in my app.So that i can know where the user is from.I've read this document :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3

But i dont know how make  'Facebook App - Configured and linked to my app, with Single Sign On enabled'.How can i make this app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create Facebook App, with Android support, you should follow this [official tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android).

If you already have one, and configured it with your Android app, you should go to the [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/), select your app, open "Settings", and in Android section turn "Single Sign-On" to enabled.

[image]

Comment: This is now outdated